# pass optional parameter in wcf service

Tags: c#, wcf, parameter-passing, wcf-data-services, optional-parameters

I had a function in WCF that takes one parameter and is being called from another application. Now, I want to add a optional parameter in the WCF so that it does not affect the method being called in the previous code.

```
getData(int number, int type=0)
```

I tried using default value in the second parameter, setting  `[WebGet(UriTemplate` but no success. If I use `IsRequired` property of `DataMember` then it will change the method call of previous code as well.

I don't want to create another WCF method. Is there any other workaround for it ?

Answer (score 3):

You can't use optional parameters when implementing an interface for a WCF.[Can't use optional parameters when implementing an interface for a WCF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17043134/cant-use-optional-parameters-when-implementing-an-interface-for-a-wcf)

Use function overloading

```
getData(int number)
getData(int number, int type)
```

Comment: It will lead to duplicate methods. I have 100+ wcf methods and don't want to duplicate them for optional parameter

Comment: http://forums.asp.net/t/1608437.aspx?can+we+use+optional+params+in+C+while+defining+service+contracts+

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass optional parameters in a Wcf service method, also you can't overload method in Wcf service with same Name. 
If you want to overload method you can use Name property to overload methods this way:

```
[OperationContract (Name = "MethodName")]
```

I resolved this issue by setting default null value in the URI so that made this parameter optional if user provided e.g: "type" value, i received it but if user didn't provide any value, in that case default value was null so that solved my problem.

Hope this answers your question.